# Monitoring DHCP clients bandwidth usage in and out

Tags: monitoring, dhcp, snmp, netflow, librenms

I have some locations that are running pfSense routers. I attempted to use the softflowd to send data to NFSen thinking that if it came from the LAN interface it might show the bandwidth per IP at least I was led to believe that.

Is there another way to monitor B/W usage from DHCP clients? I use LibreNMS for servers and network gear, but you only see usage on a per interface which does not help if you have several clients on that interface.

While pfsense does have a basic way to monitor in and out. I would like to have something with more details so I can see more perniciously what is going on.

I have thought about maybe setting up a virtualized BSD or Linux machine to pass traffic through if there was a way to monitor in some regard like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a virtual linux gateway with bandwidth monitoring features. 
Here is a prebuilt vmware image of WFilter NG firewall and guide:

http://wiki.wfilterros.com/VMWare_Image

WFilter can monitor bandwidth, record internet activities, content filter and limit bandwidth rate. It seems to be what you want.